# Anaconda OpenCV Arch Linux libselinux.so error

Tags: python, linux, opencv, anaconda

I have installed Anaconda 64 bit on a relatively fresh install of Arch.

I followed the instructions [here](https://rivercitylabs.org/up-and-running-with-opencv3-and-python-3-anaconda-edition/) to set up a virtual environment for opencv:

```
conda create -n opencv numpy scipy scikit-learn matplotlib python=3
source activate opencv
conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/menpo opencv3
```

When I run "import cv2" on the activated virtual environment I get:

```
ImportError: libselinux.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have no clue how to fix this - do I need to make kernel changes? 
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed with installing the libselinux package in the AUR:

```
yaourt -S libselinux
```

I now have **another** problem:

```
ImportError: /usr/lib/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: FcWeightToOpenType
```

Solved as in issue [368](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/368)

```
conda install -c asmeurer pango
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem you can install the missing package with:

`yaourt -S libselinux`